# String to Long conversion differs in C and Java, why?

Tags: java, c, byte, long-integer

I have one String like `"01030920316"`.
when i am going to convert this string in long and then convert in bytes then its given below output for java

```
output in java : Tag in bytes :  0, 0, 0, 0, 61, 114, -104, 124
```

same thing i do in C when i get this output

```
output in C : Tag in bytes : 124,152,114,61,0,0,0,0
```

Here I understand the different between `-104 and 152` because of signed and unsigned but why 0's at first in java and in C at last. for this behavior i am getting problem when my this bytes goes to C program side for verification.

Please explain me the where problem occurs.

Java program :

```
final byte[] tagBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(8)
                .putLong(Long.parseLong("01030920316")).array();
System.out.println("Tag in bytes  >> " + Arrays.toString(tagBytes));
```

C program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

/** To access long long values as a byte array*/
typedef union uInt64ToByte__
{
    uint64_t m_Value;
    unsigned char m_ByteArray[8];

}uInt64ToByte;

int main()
{
    uInt64ToByte longLongToByteArrayUnion;
    longLongToByteArrayUnion.m_Value = atoll("01030920316");
    printf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d",longLongToByteArrayUnion.m_ByteArray[0],longLongToByteArrayUnion.m_ByteArray[1],longLongToByteArrayUnion.m_ByteArray[2],longLongToByteArrayUnion.m_ByteArray[3],longLongToByteArrayUnion.m_ByteArray[4],longLongToByteArrayUnion.m_ByteArray[5],longLongToByteArrayUnion.m_ByteArray[6],longLongToByteArrayUnion.m_ByteArray[7]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are simply differently stored in Java and C. You have to remember that applications written in C are native and Java applications are run in Java Virtual Machine. Java byte code is platform independent and this is why your Java code would act the same on all operating systems / processor architectures. On the other hand the order of stored characters might be different in C (edit: **on different architectures**)

**Edit2:** Let's say we have a number 109 which is 1101101 binary. Why? 1 * 64 + 1 * 32 + 0 * 16 + 1 * 8 + 1 * 4 + 0 * 2 + 1 * 1 = 109. The most left bit is called "the most significant" because it's weight is the biggest (2^6 = 64) and the most right bit is called "the least significant" because it's weight is the smallest (only 1). 109 is quite boring because it can be stored in a single byte. Let's assume that we have something bigger like: 1000 which is 00000011 11101000 binary. It is stored in two bytes (let's say X and Y). Now we can save that number as XY (big-endian) or YX (little-endian). In big-endian the first byte (with the lowest address) is the most significant byte. In little-endian the first byte is the least significant byte. x86 is little-endian and JVM is big-endian. This is why the outputs are different.

Comment: It doesn't depend on C. It depends on architecture.

Comment: I wrote that. C applications are native and architecture dependent. I edited my post to make it more clear (although in my opinion it was clear before). I don't understand why you -1 me.

Comment: Means Architecture difference , C using little endian?

Comment: Can u please Give a Example of Big Endian And Little Endian? what is exactly this least significant and most significant?

Answer (score 14):

> output in java : Tag in bytes :  0, 0, 0, 0, 61, 114, -104, 124

Java's ByteBuffer is Big Endian by default and it's bytes are signed so bytes larger than 127 appear negative.

> output in C : Tag in bytes : 124,152,114,61,0,0,0,0

C's arrays use the native byte endianess which is little endian on x86/x64 systems.  The `unsigned char` will have a range of 0 to 255.

To produce the same output in Java as C you can do

```
final byte[] tagBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
        .putLong(Long.parseLong("01030920316")).array();
int[] unsigned = new int[tagBytes.length];
for (int i = 0; i < tagBytes.length; i++)
    unsigned[i] = tagBytes[i] & 0xFF;
System.out.println("Tag in bytes  >> " + Arrays.toString(unsigned));
```

prints

```
Tag in bytes  >> [124, 152, 114, 61, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: 10 sec away from posting. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html ByteBuffer is always Big Endian. You are most likely on Intel processor, so C uses Little Endian.

Comment: @jsn ByteBuffer can be changed to use little endian. AMD (as in amd64) and ARM (Android) also typically use little endian.

Comment: The format in C++ will depend on the platform and the implementation.  It's probably easier to format in C++ to match the Java format, since you have to format anyway in C++; there is no standard binary output format.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, gah, you are right. Should have said default to Big Endian.

Comment: @PeterLawrey we cant order the java bytes using order method of ByteBuffer class? And what is the difference between big Endian and little endian?

Comment: You can order the byte in Java using the `order()` method as I demonstrated.  I suggest you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Answer (score 2):

It's the difference between [BigEndian and LittleEndian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

When you convert a number on C++ into a byte array, you will notice if the underlying system is big endian (stores the most significant bytes of multi-byte integers first) or little endian (stores the least significant bytes first).

But Java, on the other hand, hides the endianness of the underlying system by always using big endian. That's part of Java's "write once - run anywhere" philosophy.

Comment: There are more issues than just endianness (although that seems to be the one he is encountering here).

Comment: @JamesKanze He said he understands the difference caused by signed vs. unsigned char, so I considered it unnecessary to explain it.

Comment: There's more than just signed and unsigned as well.  What about a C++ platform which has 4 byte `long`?

Answer (score 0):

C++ uses the native format for its types.  Java uses a standard
defined format, which corresponds to the native format on
a Sparc, but is different from that of a PC.

In general, for non-character types,  there's no reason to
assume that a dump of the bytes will be the same on two
different platforms, even if they contain the same value.
(Depending on the platforms, they may not even have the same
size.  I know of longs of 32, 36, 48 and 64 bits in C++; they're
always 64 bits in Java.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why the order seems to be reversed: This is because the `putLong` method of class `ByteBuffer` puts the bytes into the array in [big endian order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). If you want it in little endian order, set the order on the ByteBuffer:

```
final byte[] tagBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
        .putLong(Long.parseLong("01030920316")).array();
```

Second, why you get `-104` in Java where you get `152` in C: that's because in C you're using `unsigned char`, and in Java the type `byte` is signed, not unsigned. The content of the byte is actually the same, but it's shown as `-104` when you interpret it as a signed integer, and as `152` when you interpret it as an unsigned integer.

Comment: Thanks for answer and Suggestion of order bytes

Answer (score 0):

As Java's representation of an integer is not platform depended I'd take it as the reference when it goes to comparing, so I'd prefer to create C code which takes the platform dependencies of C's representation of an integer into account.

Following this I'd propose the following C code to create the byte print out as per the OP:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE  

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#if defined(__linux__)
#  include <endian.h>
#elif defined(__FreeBSD__) || defined(__NetBSD__)
#  include <sys/endian.h>
#elif defined(__OpenBSD__)
#  include <sys/types.h>
#  define be16toh(x) betoh16(x) /* -+ */
#  define be32toh(x) betoh32(x) /* -+--> not needed in this example */
#  define be64toh(x) betoh64(x) /* -+ */
#endif

int main()
{
  uint64_t uint64 = htobe64(atoll("01030920316")); /* convert to big endian/network byte order */

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(uint64); ++ i)
  {
    printf("%hhd, ", (signed char) (uint64 & 0xff));
    uint64 >>= 8;
  }

  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```